# Can I call other API's from Plivo?

Tags: android, rest, cloud, plivo

I'm trying to make an offline service using Plivo where customers can send messages but I need the message to get stored in my online database. Can Plivo connect to other API's to send the data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You will get the information on callback, When your sending message or call, just append one more attribute called URL. They will send the details on callback url. So you can use this detail to save in your database.